# Need to table to be on one page after changing font size and linespacing in document

Tags: tables

I had a table formatted nicely, however I had to change the font to 11pt and 1.5 linespacing. The table now goes over the page. Any help to getting it fitting on the page would be awesome!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\linespread{1.5} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption {Country level summary statistics \\ This table demonstrates the observations, firm count, number of investment-grade and speculative-grade corporate credit ratings for each country across the four samples utilized in this study. Panel A and B report NonESG and ESG sample statistics for developed nations, whilst Panel C and D report the aforementioned for developing nations. Countries are reported as developed or developing as defined by the United Nations \citeyearpar{un2020}.}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}
    {\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
        {\thead{Country}} & {\thead{Observations}} & {\thead{Firms}} & {\thead{Investment-\\ grade}} & {\thead{Speculative-\\ grade}} & {\thead{Observations}} & {\thead{Firms}} & {\thead{Investment-\\ grade}} & {\thead{Speculative-\\ grade}} \\
        \midrule\addlinespace
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Developed nations - NonESG}} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Developed nations - ESG}} \\
        \addlinespace
            Austria        & 311          & 6     & 252        & 59         & 195          & 5     & 184       & 11                  \\
            Australia      & 1,855        & 57    & 1,470      & 385        & 1,697        & 49    & 1,362     & 335                 \\
            Belgium        & 238          & 7     & 183        & 55         & 230          & 7     & 180       & 50                  \\
            Denmark        & 224          & 9     & 191        & 33         & 156          & 7     & 146       & 10                  \\
            Finland        & 368          & 7     & 239        & 129        & 303          & 6     & 227       & 76                  \\
            France         & 2,520        & 54    & 2,008      & 512        & 2314         & 49    & 1,932     & 382                 \\
            Germany        & 2346         & 62    & 1,464      & 882        & 1,818        & 50    & 1,248     & 570                 \\
            Greece         & 206          & 7     & 49         & 157        & 150          & 5     & 43        & 107                 \\
            Ireland        & 202          & 6     & 109        & 93         & 167          & 5     & 106       & 61                  \\
            Italy          & 1,112        & 27    & 780        & 332        & 827          & 18    & 712       & 115                 \\
            Netherlands    & 908          & 26    & 663        & 245        & 691          & 17    & 598       & 93                  \\
            New Zealand    & 389          & 12    & 366        & 23         & 292          & 9     & 291       & 1                   \\
            Norway         & 380          & 10    & 246        & 134        & 366          & 9     & 240       & 126                 \\
            Spain          & 865          & 28    & 618        & 247        & 694          & 25    & 601       & 93                  \\
            Sweden         & 971          & 26    & 837        & 134        & 911          & 24    & 814       & 97                  \\
            Switzerland    & 829          & 24    & 686        & 143        & 713          & 23    & 630       & 83                  \\
            United Kingdom & 3,365        & 112   & 2,332      & 1033       & 3,066        & 101   & 2,210     & 856                 \\
            United States  & 85,480       & 1,854 & 44,445     & 41,035     & 25,632       & 768   & 16,282    & 9,350               \\
        \addlinespace 
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Panel C: Developing nations - NonESG}} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel D: Developing nations - ESG}} \\
        \addlinespace
            Argentina      & 412          & 10    & 1          & 411        & 71           & 8     & 0         & 71                  \\
            Brazil         & 2,049        & 53    & 670        & 1,379      & 1,042        & 34    & 443       & 599                 \\
            Chile          & 811          & 22    & 566        & 245        & 433          & 14    & 342       & 91                  \\
            Colombia       & 146          & 4     & 129        & 17         & 94           & 4     & 93        & 1                   \\
            Hong Kong      & 597          & 15    & 526        & 71         & 554          & 13    & 510       & 44                  \\
            India          & 487          & 20    & 248        & 239        & 357          & 13    & 213       & 144                 \\
            Indonesia      & 946          & 37    & 38         & 908        & 248          & 9     & 38        & 210                 \\
            Israel         & 132          & 5     & 107        & 25         & 97           & 2     & 97        & 0                   \\
            Kazakhstan     & 120          & 5     & 17         & 103        & 32           & 1     & 12        & 20                  \\
            Malaysia       & 388          & 12    & 348        & 40         & 252          & 8     & 244       & 8                   \\
            Mexico         & 1,224        & 36    & 529        & 695        & 448          & 17    & 394       & 54                  \\
            Peru           & 244          & 10    & 78         & 166        & 91           & 8     & 20        & 71                  \\
            Philippines    & 137          & 5     & 35         & 102        & 60           & 2     & 34        & 26                  \\
            Russia         & 1,066        & 38    & 409        & 657        & 732          & 24    & 383       & 349                 \\
            Singapore      & 377          & 14    & 307        & 70         & 253          & 7     & 247       & 6                   \\
            Taiwan         & 333          & 11    & 330        & 3          & 291          & 9     & 291       & 0                   \\
            Thailand       & 491          & 14    & 378        & 113        & 262          & 9     & 212       & 50                  \\
            South Africa   & 152          & 5     & 76         & 76         & 123          & 5     & 65        & 58                  \\
            South Korea    & 691          & 24    & 657        & 34         & 678          & 23    & 647       & 31                 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example produces `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.`  and `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> ... by the United Nations \citeyearpar`

Answer (score 2):

Never apply `\resizebox` to tables, just choose an appropriate font size.

This could be tidied up more but to get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\linespread{1.5} 
\def\citeyearpar{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
   \caption {Country level summary statistics \\ This table demonstrates the observations, firm count, number of investment-grade and speculative-grade corporate credit ratings for each country across the four samples utilized in this study. Panel A and B report NonESG and ESG sample statistics for developed nations, whilst Panel C and D report the aforementioned for developing nations. Countries are reported as developed or developing as defined by the United Nations \citeyearpar{un2020}.}
    \centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{.7}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
        {\thead{Country}} & {\thead{Observations}} & {\thead{Firms}} & {\thead{Investment-\\ grade}} & {\thead{Speculative-\\ grade}} & {\thead{Observations}} & {\thead{Firms}} & {\thead{Investment-\\ grade}} & {\thead{Speculative-\\ grade}} \\
        \midrule\addlinespace
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Developed nations - NonESG}} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Developed nations - ESG}} \\
        \addlinespace
            Austria        & 311          & 6     & 252        & 59         & 195          & 5     & 184       & 11                  \\
            Australia      & 1,855        & 57    & 1,470      & 385        & 1,697        & 49    & 1,362     & 335                 \\
            Belgium        & 238          & 7     & 183        & 55         & 230          & 7     & 180       & 50                  \\
            Denmark        & 224          & 9     & 191        & 33         & 156          & 7     & 146       & 10                  \\
            Finland        & 368          & 7     & 239        & 129        & 303          & 6     & 227       & 76                  \\
            France         & 2,520        & 54    & 2,008      & 512        & 2314         & 49    & 1,932     & 382                 \\
            Germany        & 2346         & 62    & 1,464      & 882        & 1,818        & 50    & 1,248     & 570                 \\
            Greece         & 206          & 7     & 49         & 157        & 150          & 5     & 43        & 107                 \\
            Ireland        & 202          & 6     & 109        & 93         & 167          & 5     & 106       & 61                  \\
            Italy          & 1,112        & 27    & 780        & 332        & 827          & 18    & 712       & 115                 \\
            Netherlands    & 908          & 26    & 663        & 245        & 691          & 17    & 598       & 93                  \\
            New Zealand    & 389          & 12    & 366        & 23         & 292          & 9     & 291       & 1                   \\
            Norway         & 380          & 10    & 246        & 134        & 366          & 9     & 240       & 126                 \\
            Spain          & 865          & 28    & 618        & 247        & 694          & 25    & 601       & 93                  \\
            Sweden         & 971          & 26    & 837        & 134        & 911          & 24    & 814       & 97                  \\
            Switzerland    & 829          & 24    & 686        & 143        & 713          & 23    & 630       & 83                  \\
            United Kingdom & 3,365        & 112   & 2,332      & 1033       & 3,066        & 101   & 2,210     & 856                 \\
            United States  & 85,480       & 1,854 & 44,445     & 41,035     & 25,632       & 768   & 16,282    & 9,350               \\
        \addlinespace 
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Panel C: Developing nations - NonESG}} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Panel D: Developing nations - ESG}} \\
        \addlinespace
            Argentina      & 412          & 10    & 1          & 411        & 71           & 8     & 0         & 71                  \\
            Brazil         & 2,049        & 53    & 670        & 1,379      & 1,042        & 34    & 443       & 599                 \\
            Chile          & 811          & 22    & 566        & 245        & 433          & 14    & 342       & 91                  \\
            Colombia       & 146          & 4     & 129        & 17         & 94           & 4     & 93        & 1                   \\
            Hong Kong      & 597          & 15    & 526        & 71         & 554          & 13    & 510       & 44                  \\
            India          & 487          & 20    & 248        & 239        & 357          & 13    & 213       & 144                 \\
            Indonesia      & 946          & 37    & 38         & 908        & 248          & 9     & 38        & 210                 \\
            Israel         & 132          & 5     & 107        & 25         & 97           & 2     & 97        & 0                   \\
            Kazakhstan     & 120          & 5     & 17         & 103        & 32           & 1     & 12        & 20                  \\
            Malaysia       & 388          & 12    & 348        & 40         & 252          & 8     & 244       & 8                   \\
            Mexico         & 1,224        & 36    & 529        & 695        & 448          & 17    & 394       & 54                  \\
            Peru           & 244          & 10    & 78         & 166        & 91           & 8     & 20        & 71                  \\
            Philippines    & 137          & 5     & 35         & 102        & 60           & 2     & 34        & 26                  \\
            Russia         & 1,066        & 38    & 409        & 657        & 732          & 24    & 383       & 349                 \\
            Singapore      & 377          & 14    & 307        & 70         & 253          & 7     & 247       & 6                   \\
            Taiwan         & 333          & 11    & 330        & 3          & 291          & 9     & 291       & 0                   \\`
            Thailand       & 491          & 14    & 378        & 113        & 262          & 9     & 212       & 50                  \\
            South Africa   & 152          & 5     & 76         & 76         & 123          & 5     & 65        & 58                  \\
            South Korea    & 691          & 24    & 657        & 34         & 678          & 23    & 647       & 31                 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar as suggested @David Carlisle in his answer (+1).

If you allowed to have tightly spaced table body, than you can still fit table on one page using `normalsize` font. O
With some off-topic suggestions, your table can be as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % new
\usepackage{xparse}                         % new
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{1}m}    % new
    {\multicolumn{#1}{l}{#2}}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\linespread{1.5}
\def\citeyearpar{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
\caption[Country level summary statistics]{Country level summary statistics \\
    This table demonstrates the observations, firm count, number of investment-grade and speculative-grade corporate credit ratings for each country across the four samples utilized in this study. Panel A and B report NonESG and ESG sample statistics for developed nations, whilst Panel C and D report the aforementioned for developing nations. Countries are reported as developed or developing as defined by the United Nations \citeyearpar{un2020}.}

\sisetup{table-format=5.0,
         group-minimum-digits = 3,
         group-separator={\,}
         }
\linespread{0.96}\selectfont  % <----
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}     % <----

    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l % <----
                                SS[table-format=4.0]SS   % <----
                                SS[table-format=4.0]SS}  % <----
    \toprule
\thead{Country}
    &   {\thead{Observations}}
        &   {\thead{Firms}}
            &   {\thead{Investment\\ grade}}
                &   {\thead{Speculative\\ grade}}
                    &   {\thead{Observations}}
                        &   {\thead{Firms}}
                            &   {\thead{Investment\\ grade}}
                                &   {\thead{Speculative\\ grade}} \\
    \midrule
\mcl[5]{\textit{Panel A: Developed nations - NonESG}}  
    &   \mcl[4]{\textit{Panel B: Developed nations - ESG}}  \\
    \cmidrule{1-5}   % <----
    \cmidrule{6-9}   % <----
Austria         & 311       & 6     & 252       & 59        & 195       & 5     & 184       & 11    \\
Australia       & 1 855     & 57    & 1 470     & 385       & 1 697     & 49    & 1 362     & 335   \\
Belgium         & 238       & 7     & 183       & 55        & 230       & 7     & 180       & 50    \\
Denmark         & 224       & 9     & 191       & 33        & 156       & 7     & 146       & 10    \\
Finland         & 368       & 7     & 239       & 129       & 303       & 6     & 227       & 76    \\
France          & 2 520     & 54    & 2 008     & 512       & 2314      & 49    & 1 932     & 382   \\
Germany         & 2346      & 62    & 1 464     & 882       & 1 818     & 50    & 1 248     & 570   \\
Greece          & 206       & 7     & 49        & 157       & 150       & 5     & 43        & 107   \\
Ireland         & 202       & 6     & 109       & 93        & 167       & 5     & 106       & 61    \\
Italy           & 1 112     & 27    & 780       & 332       & 827       & 18    & 712       & 115   \\
Netherlands     & 908       & 26    & 663       & 245       & 691       & 17    & 598       & 93    \\
New Zealand     & 389       & 12    & 366       & 23        & 292       & 9     & 291       & 1     \\
Norway          & 380       & 10    & 246       & 134       & 366       & 9     & 240       & 126   \\
Spain           & 865       & 28    & 618       & 247       & 694       & 25    & 601       & 93    \\
Sweden          & 971       & 26    & 837       & 134       & 911       & 24    & 814       & 97    \\
Switzerland     & 829       & 24    & 686       & 143       & 713       & 23    & 630       & 83    \\
United Kingdom  & 3 365     & 112   & 2 332     & 1033      & 3 066     & 101   & 2 210     & 856   \\
United States   & 85 480    & 1 854 & 44 445    & 41 035    & 25 632    & 768   & 16 282    & 9 350 \\
        \addlinespace
\mcl[5]{\textit{Panel C: Developing nations - NonESG}}
    &   \mcl[4]{\textit{Panel D: Developing nations - ESG}} \\
    \cmidrule{1-5}   % <----
    \cmidrule{6-9}   % <----
Argentina       & 412       & 10    & 1         & 411       & 71        & 8     & 0         & 71    \\
Brazil          & 2 049     & 53    & 670       & 1 379     & 1 042     & 34    & 443       & 599   \\
Chile           & 811       & 22    & 566       & 245       & 433       & 14    & 342       & 91    \\
Colombia        & 146       & 4     & 129       & 17        & 94        & 4     & 93        & 1     \\
Hong Kong       & 597       & 15    & 526       & 71        & 554       & 13    & 510       & 44    \\
India           & 487       & 20    & 248       & 239       & 357       & 13    & 213       & 144   \\
Indonesia       & 946       & 37    & 38        & 908       & 248       & 9     & 38        & 210   \\
Israel          & 132       & 5     & 107       & 25        & 97        & 2     & 97        & 0     \\
Kazakhstan      & 120       & 5     & 17        & 103       & 32        & 1     & 12        & 20    \\
Malaysia        & 388       & 12    & 348       & 40        & 252       & 8     & 244       & 8     \\
Mexico          & 1 224     & 36    & 529       & 695       & 448       & 17    & 394       & 54    \\
Peru            & 244       & 10    & 78        & 166       & 91        & 8     & 20        & 71    \\
Philippines     & 137       & 5     & 35        & 102       & 60        & 2     & 34        & 26    \\
Russia          & 1 066     & 38    & 409       & 657       & 732       & 24    & 383       & 349   \\
Singapore       & 377       & 14    & 307       & 70        & 253       & 7     & 247       & 6     \\
Taiwan          & 333       & 11    & 330       & 3         & 291       & 9     & 291       & 0     \\ Thailand        & 491       & 14    & 378       & 113       & 262       & 9     & 212       & 50    \\
South Africa    & 152       & 5     & 76        & 76        & 123       & 5     & 65        & 58    \\
South Korea     & 691       & 24    & 657       & 34        & 678       & 23    & 647       & 31    \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In comparison to your table code, the following changes are done:

- inter row space is reduced by `\linespread{0.96}\selectfont`
- for table is used ˙tabular*` environment
- column separation is calculated by `\extracolsep` macro
- for the first column is used `l` type, others are `S` columns
- for group separator are instead of commas used small spaces

[image]

(red lines show text borders)